# What is advantage to call session bean method by creating local object

Tags: java, ejb

Calling session Bean method directly

```
/**
     * @ejb.interface-method view-type="both"
*/
public String test(String name, prefix, int length) {
  int nSeq = test2(name);
}
```

Calling session bean method by creating local session bean object

```
/**
             * @ejb.interface-method view-type="both"
        */
        public String test(String name, prefix, int length) {
        ITestSessionBeanLocal testSessionBean = (ITestSessionBeanLocal)_ctx.getEJBLocalObject();
            int nSeq = testSessionBean.test2(name);
        }
```

Other Method of session bean

```
 /**
             * @ejb.interface-method view-type="both"
        */
        public String test2(String name) {
          //Code
        }
```

What is advantage to call session bean method by creating local object ?